# Different outcomes by Python IDLE and VS Code python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, exception, python-idle

On executing the following code.

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didnt understand that.\n")      #On Inputting a non-integer numeral
        continue

    if number < 623:
        print("Input should be more than or equal to 623.\n")    #On Inputting number greater than 623
        continue
    elif number > 1920:
        print("Input should be less than or equal to 1920.\n")   #On Inputting number less than 1920
        continue
    else:
        break           #On Inputting the Desired Input, The Loop breaks
```

#### Like Python IDLE, I was expecting same results in VS Code Python.

In Python IDLE It works just as intended   [[**View Screenshot**]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3noin.jpg)

In VS Code, the same code gives out error [[**View Screenshot**]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ZHj.jpg)

My Python IDLE and VS Code Python Interpreter have the same version installed i.e. `3.10.10`

Comment: It's beacause you have different version, update your VS code python to 3.10.30 and check if the output is the same

Comment: Try to fix your formatting, code inside except block is overly indented.

Comment: Definitely works in VS Code with 3.10.9 and correct indentation

Comment: are you sure you use Python 3.x on VSC, on Mac default python is 2.x, what is the command shown in the terminal

Comment: @executable On updating my python in VS Code, I've now same version (3.10.10) but its NOT working :(

Comment: The sample code you provided is wrong. Please modify the correct format and code. Screenshots should also show the full content.           Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu Thanks for reaching out, but shouldn't the code look concise and relevant to the actual problem? Full screenshots are not required as I only want to indicate the "error"

Comment: @JialeDu I've made the necessary changes!

Comment: There is [no error](https://imgur.com/sbbyqu8.png) in the same situation. Whether you configure *Launch.json*? if so, please display the content.

Comment: @JialeDu [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/829017858038169611/1082239660018901054/image.png) I've not much clue how about configuring Launch.json but I guess that was it?

Comment: @Inferno, Yes, it looks no problem. But in the same circumstances, there is no problem here. I'm sorry to delay your time, but if you want, you can add more information, such as your detailed operation steps (or a GIF?), More information about your settings, etc.    Or you can report your question directly on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) to get the response from official personnel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the counter variable, which counts the number of times the loop has iterated, the code should print the value of x, which is the current multiple of the jump variable.

So the correct code for the loop will be.......

```py
for x in range(0, number, jump):
    print(x)
    counter += 1
```

This will print out all the multiples of the jump variable between 0 and the input number, and also count the number of multiples that were printed.

Comment: The code program has not been completed yet. As I mentioned in the title, I was expecting similar outcomes, but it gives an error in VS code. I want a fix for that.

Comment: Check your indentations, make sure it is exactly the same.

Comment: @HighZedd yes indentations are correct